# Longer silence during audio recording

Tags: flutter

I make a sound recording in Flutter using the flutter_sound_record package, it works, but I find that after about 30 minutes there is several minutes of silence in the recording, and then there is sound again, I don't know what causes this.

This error only becomes apparent when the recording is played back. Maybe you have an idea how to detect this error or somehow react to it?
I tested it on several Android versions and it always appears randomly during longer recordings. No error messages during recording.